# Ansible playbook fails to assign static IP address with vmware_guest module

Tags: vmware, ansible

I am attempting to build a VM from template with ansible. I need to specify IP address.  All other configs work in the playbook. It is not a syntax issue. This is a lab so I do not have a vlan to use for config. I must use the network name. SystemsLab is a valid standard port group.

According to ansible doc for vmware_guest network:

> networks
>
> "A list of networks (in the order of the NICs).
>   Removing NICs is not allowed, while reconfiguring the virtual machine.
>   All parameters and VMware object names are case sensitive.
>
> One of the below parameters is required per entry:
>
> - name (string): Name of the portgroup or distributed virtual portgroup for this interface. When specifying distributed virtual portgroup make sure given esxi_hostname or cluster is associated with it.
> - vlan (integer): VLAN number for this interface."

Here is my playbook entry for VM configuration:

```
- name: Create VM from template
     vmware_guest:
       validate_certs: False
       hostname: "{{ vcenter_hostname }}"
       username: "{{ vcenter_user }}"
       password: "{{ vcenter_pass }}"
       esxi_hostname: lab-vmsystems-01
       datacenter: Lab
       name: testvm_1
       template: RHEL74-IMG
       folder: template
       datastore: autoselect_datastore
       networks:
         - name: "SystemsLab"
           type: static
           device_type: vmxnet3
           ip: 10.**.**.199
           netmask: 255.255.255.0
           gateway: 10.**.**.1
         - dns_servers:
           - 10.**.**.21
           - 10.**.**.22
         - domain: ****.net
```

Here is the error I am getting.

````
    "changed": false,
    "invocation": {
        "module_args": {
            "annotation": null,
            "cdrom": {},
            "cluster": null,
            "convert": null,
            "customization": {},
            "customization_spec": null,
            "customvalues": [],
            "datacenter": "Lab",
            "datastore": "autoselect_datastore",
            "disk": [],
            "esxi_hostname": "lab-vmsystems-01",
            "folder": "template",
            "force": false,
            "guest_id": null,
            "hardware": {
                "memory_mb": "1024",
                "num_cpus": 1
            },
            "hostname": "***-vcenter-01",
            "is_template": false,
            "linked_clone": false,
            "name": "testvm_1",
            "name_match": "first",
            "networks": [
                {
                    "device_type": "vmxnet3",
                    "gateway": "10.**.**.1",
                    "ip": "10.**.**.199",
                    "name": "SystemsLab",
                    "netmask": "255.255.255.0",
                    "type": "static"
                },
                {
                    "dns_servers": [
                        "10.**.**.21",
                        "10.**.**.22"
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "domain": "****.net"
                }
            ],
            "password": "VALUE_SPECIFIED_IN_NO_LOG_PARAMETER",
            "port": 443,
            "resource_pool": null,
            "snapshot_src": null,
            "state": "present",
            "state_change_timeout": 0,
            "template": "RHEL74-IMG",
            "use_instance_uuid": false,
            "username": "***@***.net",
            "uuid": null,
            "validate_certs": false,
            "vapp_properties": [],
            "wait_for_customization": false,
            "wait_for_ip_address": true
        }
    },
    "msg": "Please specify at least a network name or a VLAN name under VM network list."```

C:\Program Files (x86)\VMware\VMware vSphere CLI>dcli +server lvd-vcenter-01 com vmware vcenter network list +skip-server-verification
|----------|----------|------------------|
|Network   |Name      |Type              |
|----------|----------|------------------|
|network-31|VM Network|STANDARD_PORTGROUP|
|network-32|SystemsLab|STANDARD_PORTGROUP|
|----------|----------|------------------|
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're creating three network interfaces:

```
"networks": [
                {
                    "device_type": "vmxnet3",
                    "gateway": "10.**.**.1",
                    "ip": "10.**.**.199",
                    "name": "SystemsLab",
                    "netmask": "255.255.255.0",
                    "type": "static"
                },
                {
                    "dns_servers": [
                        "10.**.**.21",
                        "10.**.**.22"
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "domain": "****.net"
                }
            ],
```

remove the dashes for dns_servers and domain:

```
- name: Create VM from template
     vmware_guest:
       validate_certs: False
       hostname: "{{ vcenter_hostname }}"
       username: "{{ vcenter_user }}"
       password: "{{ vcenter_pass }}"
       esxi_hostname: lab-vmsystems-01
       datacenter: Lab
       name: testvm_1
       template: RHEL74-IMG
       folder: template
       datastore: autoselect_datastore
       networks:
         - name: "SystemsLab"
           type: static
           device_type: vmxnet3
           ip: 10.**.**.199
           netmask: 255.255.255.0
           gateway: 10.**.**.1
           dns_servers:
             - 10.**.**.21
             - 10.**.**.22
           domain: ****.net
```

Comment: That worked. Thanks so much! I find that most issues stem from yaml formatting.

Comment: No problem. You get used to the yaml, I spotted it before I read the error message :-) It helps if you see "networks" is a list of all the network interfaces, so every "-" you use is a new interface. If it's clear please tick the green checkmark next to my reply so everyone can see this question has been answered